# How to use RTP protocol in ios

Tags: ios, rtp

I want to create an app which plays videos using the RTP protocol.

I just need to know if anyone can provide any resources/websites, as to where I can find information on how to use the RTP protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the RFC's?

RTP RFC 3550:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3550.txt

Also you should take a look at the RTCP protocol for controlling an RTP stream.

RTCP RFC 3605:
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3605.txt

For implementing a RTP server in C++ you could take a look at JRTPLIB:
http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/~jori/page/index.php?n=CS.Jrtplib